# Overwriting when updating two models with has_many through association in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, sql-update, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models. Meal and Food. A meal can have multiple food items and a food item can be a part of multiple meals. They have a many to many association done with has_many through. The join model is called MealFood.
My problem is when updating the meal. You can choose the food items that you want when editing a meal. When I add new food items only they get saved to the db. The rest get deleted.

Here's my code:

**Meals Controller**

```
def edit
    @meal_foods = @meal.meal_foods.includes(:food)
end

def update
    if @meal.update(meal_params)
        @meal.update(total_calories: @meal.calc_total_calories, total_carbohydrates:    @meal.calc_total_carbohydrates, total_proteins: @meal.calc_total_proteins, total_fat: @meal.calc_total_fat)

        redirect_to @meal, notice: "Successfully updated meal."
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

**Meal Model**

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :meal_foods, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :foods, through: :meal_foods
end
```

**Food Model**

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :meal_foods
    has_many :meals, through: :meal_foods
end
```

**MealFood Model**

```
class MealFood < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :food
end
```

**Log when updating**
[image]
[image]

**Edit View**

```
<%= form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :meal_type %>
        <%= f.select :meal_type, ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Morning Snack", "Afternoon Snack", "Evening Snack"] %>
    </div>

    <% @meal_foods.each do |mf| %>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="input-dropdown">Food Item</label>
            <%= select_tag "meal[food_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(Food.where(id: mf.food_id), "id", "name"), {:disabled => true} %>

            <ul class="sub-buttons">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-food">Add Food Item</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete-food">Delete Food Item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field submit">
        <%= f.submit class: "button button-highlight button-block" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In the edit view when you click "add food item" the following function gets called:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.add-food', function() {
            var openingDiv = "<div class='field'>"
            var label = "<label>Food Item</label>"
            var partial = "<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'new_field') %>"
            var closingDiv = "</div>"

            $(openingDiv + label + partial + closingDiv).insertBefore(".submit");
        })

        $(document).on('click', '.delete-food', function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
        })
    })
</script>
```

which then renders this partial:

```
<%= select_tag "meal[food_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(Food.all, "id", "name") %>

<ul class="sub-buttons">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-food">Add Food Item</a>
    </li><li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete-food">Delete Food Item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is not in the meal_params, as I've done **permit!** to accept all attributes.

Comment: Could you show the logs for the request? And seeing the way your models are set up may help as well.

Comment: I updated my questions.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra details. The log is showing a GET request though - are you sure that's the right log?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My mistake. I updated the question once again.

Comment: Could you show the form view?

Comment: Yup. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your logs you'll see that you're passing in this param for the update `"food_ids"=>["15", "17"]`. And then further down the log you'll see that the MealFood record joining your Meal and Food 16 is being deleted.

This makes sense because you're telling rails that your Meal should only be associated with Food 15 and 17 (ie. your update call doesn't append 15 and 17 to the existing value, it replaces the existing value with 15 and 17).

The problem is likely that your edit form isn't including the current foods. If you make sure your form submits both new and current foods in your `food_ids` field you should be good to go.

**UPDATE:**

When you're rendering the existing foods, the fields for them are disabled. When you submit a form, rails ignores any disabled fields and doesn't include them in the params that get sent to your controller.

In order to get this working, you'll need to enable the existing food fields.

If you don't want users to manipulate existing foods, you could still keep your existing fields disabled, but add hidden fields (that are enabled) for the existing food ids.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "meal[food_ids][]", mf.food_id %>
```

And since those disabled select tags don't really offer much utility, it might be worth considering removing them and just rendering the names of the food in a `p` or `li` for example.

Comment: How do I make sure that I'm submitting both? I updated my question so you can now see the form.

Comment: Ok just to need to clarify a couple things. When you actually use the UI of the form, are all foods rendered (existing and new) when you submit the form (so in this case 3 foods with id's 15, 16, 17)? It looks like you're rendering a disabled dropdown with one option here `<%= select_tag "meal[food_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(Food.where(id: mf.food_id), "id", "name"), {:disabled => true} %>` is that the case? And if it is, what's that doing for you? When you click "Add Food Item" what is rendered?

Comment: So yes when you go to the edit page all your added from the creation food items are displayed as each is in a disabled select option. When you click "add food item" a select menu appears in which you select the food item that you want.

Comment: Is it rendering a partial or something like that? I'd need to see some code - I feel like we're close, but I can't see exactly what's happening yet.

Comment: Thanks - I missed something earlier. Rails doesn't submit params from disabled form fields. You'll just need to enable those fields from the existing foods in order to get them to submit. I'll update my answer with more details.